# Crop the footer from PDF using Ghostscript

Tags: c#, ghostscript

I am trying to crop the bottom inch of a PDF with Ghostscript and C#.

When I run my code, it successfully creates the new PDF, but it is completely blank. My understanding of `gsArgsList.Add(" -c \"[/CropBox [0 72 0 0] /PAGES pdfmark\"");` is that is will crop 72pt (1 inch) off of the bottom of the page. I've included some code in hopes someone will see something obvious.

I have played with the 4 number parameters of CropBox but no matter what I pass, it always results in a blank PDF. I only want to remove the footer.

**UPDATE - My code now shows the working solution.**

```
/// <summary>
/// Crop the bottom inch from the temporary PDF file using GhostScript.
/// A new PDF file (test_cropped.pdf) will be created with the modifications.
/// </summary>
/// <param name="tempPDF">the path to the temporary PDF</param>
/// <param name="croppedPDF">the path to the modified PDF</param>
public static void cropPDFFooter(string inputPDF, string outputPDF, string pdfPostScript)
{
     try
        {
            string gsPath = @"C:\gs\gs9.14\bin\gswin64c.exe";

            List<string> gsArgsList = new List<string>();
            gsArgsList.Add(" -o " + outputFile);
            gsArgsList.Add(" -sDEVICE=pdfwrite");
            gsArgsList.Add(" -o " + outputFile + " -c \"mark /.HWMargins [ 0.0 288.0 0.0 0.0 ] .dicttomark setpagedevice\" -f " + inputFile + "");

            var gsArgs = String.Join(null, gsArgsList);

            System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(gsPath, gsArgs);

        }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(ex.ToString());
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ghostscript also supports .HWMargins [ lx by rx uy ] which is an array of four reals that are the margins in points (1/72 inch). If I do:

```
 gs -sDEVICE=pdfwrite -o x.pdf \
    -c "mark /.HWMargins [ 144.0 288.0 0.0 0.0 ] .dicttomark setpagedevice" \
    -f examples/annots.pdf
```

Then the output has the left two inches cropped and the bottom 4 inches cropped.

Note that this can be used with `-dPDFFitPage -dFIXEDMEDIA` before the `-c` and the page will be fit (with all information including footers) to the page with the larger margins.

There is no way to fit a page to a smaller size AND crop part of it in a single pass through Ghostscript (AFAIK).

Answer (score 1):

The pdfwrite device simply maintains much of the content of an input PDF file. Your CropBox pdfmark will simply be overwritten by the CropBox from the input PDF file (it would work for PostScript input, provided there are no other CropBox pdfmarks in the PostScript file).

If ou want to alter the page size and contents you could try putting the PostScript containing the CropBox into a file and add that file as an input file *after* the input PDF file on the command line.

Alternatively you could set the page size you want using the -sPAPERSIZE or -g switches, and also set the -dFIXEDMEDIA switch but note that in PostScript the origin (0,0) is bottom left and so you would also have to translate the origin. This is probably more difficult than you want to get into, so I would suggest you try placing the pdfmark into a separate file and add it to the command line after the input PDF file that you want modified.

Comment: All I really want to do is remove the footer from the PDF. It takes up about .5" of the page. I'd actually like it if the page stayed the original size. I'm struggling to understand GhostScript :(

Comment: removing content is *much* harder, I'd stick with modifying the crop box. Just put your pdfmark in a text file, then do: gs -sDEVICE=pdfwrite -sOutputFile=<out.pdf> <input.pdf> <pdfmark.ps>

Comment: I made my pdfMark.ps read the following: `%! 0 0 250 250 rectfill` additionally, I did what you said, and my script is minimal. (see the updated code question). It doesn't work anymore though. It doesn't create a new PDF.

Comment: Is it not possible to make a cropbox that just covers the existing content? That's what I thought I was doing initially.

Comment: The '<' and '>' are meant to show you where to put your filenames, I didn't intend that you would actually put those in the arguments.....